# Internet working but not all of LAN!

Tags: networking, centos

I have recently installed CentOS 6.5. system is behind a firewall (institutional access) with an IP address, say, 10.50.28.99. It is not detecting (pinging or connecting via ssh) computers with similar address i.e. 10.50.28.xx are unavailable but internet and other lan pc with different IP address like say 10.50.1.1 are easily connected. I have tried disabling iptables altogether but that did not help.

Comment: can you add the result of a `ipconfig -a` and `route -n` so we can really help you ?

Comment: Thank you for reply but i reinstalled OS and now its fine.